# How to downgrade a kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rpm, yum

I need to downgrade the kernel from 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.centos.plus.x86_64
to 
2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64

I am unable to install the older version using Yum/rpm as it gives the following error

```
root@localhost kernels]# rpm -i --ignoreos kernel-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm 
warning: kernel-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID  
192a7d7d: NOKEY
package kernel-2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 (which is newer than kernel-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64) is already installed
package kernel-2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 (which is newer than kernel-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64) is already installed
package kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 (which is newer than kernel-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64) is already installed
```

I cant remove the currently running kernel , so whats the way out?

Yum search doesnt even get me to this old version, so had to get the rpm from web.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with `rpm` but can't you remove the current kernel package and then install the lower version one?  The kernel isn't actually in effect until your reboot next.  I'm not sure if CentOS/Redhat does this, but in Debian, when you upgrade your kernel with a kernel package, the previous kernel can be selected in the bootloader still.  You might be able to do this too.

Comment: @ultrasawblade: There's no need to remove the old kernel. Fedora-based distros allow multiple `kernel` packages to be installed; the trick is to use `-i` (instead of `-U`) and `--oldpackage`.

Comment: @JATMON  Actually what you need to do is get a linux with a modern kernel version.  The current version is 3.9.6 your centos version is using an ancient kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rpm -ivh <kernel.rpm> --oldpackage`
 does the job in centos

This will install your kernel, now make sure the grub entries are proper and then you can reboot and boot into this kernal

Answer (score 3):

Actually, downgrade wouldn't work for kernel. The right command would be localinstall:

```
#yum localinstall ./kernel....rpm
```

If you have more then 5 kernels yum will delete oldest.